# Why we write false while moving from one page to an other page

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

Moving from one page to other the code is
 Response.Redirect("AddElementTitle.aspx", false);
My question is that why we write false as if we not write false than also page is move to other page. Please tell me why we write false.

Answer (score 1):

A Google search of `Response.Redirect` very quickly leads you here [HttpResponse.Redirect Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  where the `endResponse` parameter is described as:

> Indicates whether execution of the current page should terminate

Answer (score 0):

`HttpResponse.Redirect` has two overloads. [HttpResponse.Redirect Method (String, Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28VS.80%29.aspx) takes a boolean parameter whether the execution of current page should be aborted or not.

If you pass `true` this function will call `Response.End` and current thread will be aborted.

You should keep in mind that, if this value is `false` then all code after the redirect code will execute.

I assume that the common approach is to use [HttpResponse.Redirect Method (String)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9dwyts4%28VS.80%29.aspx) method which is equivalent to calling [HttpResponse.Redirect Method (String, Boolean)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28VS.80%29.aspx) with a `true` value, that ends the response and aborts the execution of current page.